How do I unclutter child class's constructor?
I have an abstract parent class with 10 variables that needs to be initialized when I create child class's objects. I am using lombok.
My child class's constructor looks like this:
ChildClassName(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f, G g, H h, I i, J j) {
    super(a,b,c,d,e,g,f,h,i,j);
}

It looks simple here but when its written with full class and variable name, this constructor code covers more lines than other code in the child class. There are multiple child classes so I have constructor like this in all of them.
What pattern can I use to make it better? Is there a lombok annotation that I can use to fix it?
I tried to use @SuperBuilder from lombok but it does not work.

How exactly SuperBuilder doesn't work?

It's easier to show your specific class instead of a meaningless example with lots of letters that don't tell anyone anything. What are the parameters? Do they all have to be set or are some optional? Can some be grouped together or encapsulated in a separate class? Are some of them of the same type so that you can pass a list or a map instead of individual parameters?

SuperBuilder fails with an error "java: can't find symbol BaseClassNameBuilder

The problem is exactly what is mentioned above, I have asked what pattern may solve this problem. I have got answers who already understood my question, had you encountered this problem you might have understood it as well Asmir.

Your BaseClassName lacks a @SuperBuilder. You need @SuperBuilder on all classes in your inheritance chain.

I tried that as well, it fails with error Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ChildClass]: No default constructor found, when I run this child class unit test.
If its relevant I have @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation on Base class.

Spring does not support builders to instantiate. You need an additional regular constructor.

One option is to group the parameters into one or more separate classes and pass those into the constructor.  In your example, that would look something like this:
class SuperOptions {
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;
  D d;
  E e;
  F f;
  G g;
  H h;
  I i;
  J j;
}
    
ChildClassName(SuperOptions options) { super(options); }

If the child class needs additional stuff passed to the constructor you can either add a parameter just for that or create a new type derived from SuperOptions and add it there
//new parameter
ChildClassName(SuperOptions options, ChildDependency k) { super(options); }

Or
//derive from SuperOptions
class ChildOptions extends SuperOptions {
  ChildDependency k;
}

ChildClassName(ChildOptions options) { super(options); }

These will work best if the constructor is called from user code.  If you are using dependency injection to create these objects, this will be tedious.

Unfortunately I am using dependency injection

Looks like you could use a Builder Design Pattern
In essence, you create a static nested class and a private builder Constructor.  Then, you set the attributes you need to 'build' your instance.  Read the article above for more details and the sample code below:
public class Person {
    // Attributes of the Person class
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;
    private final String email;

    // Private constructor to be called by the Builder
    private Person(Builder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.email = builder.email;
    }

    // Getters for the Person attributes
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    // Static nested Builder class
    public static class Builder {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;
        private String email;

        // Setter methods for each attribute, returning the Builder object
        public Builder setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
            return this;
        }

        // Build method to create a Person instance
        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using the Builder to create a Person instance
        Person person = new Person.Builder()
                .setFirstName("John")
                .setLastName("Doe")
                .setAge(30)
                .setEmail("john.doe@example.com")
                .build();

        // Using the Builder to create a Second Person instance (with fewer attributes initialized)
        Person person2 = new Person.Builder()
                .setFirstName("Jane")
                .setEmail("jane.doe@example.com")
                .build();


        // Output the Person instance
        System.out.println(person);
        System.out.println(person2);
    }
}


